# Time required by robot to traverse a 2D grid with obstacles

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

There is a 2D grid of integers having value 1 or 0 (1 for obstacle and 0 for land). Calculate the minimum time required by a robot to clean all land cells. Robot is initially placed at (x,y). It can move in 4 directions (Left/Right/Up/Down).
Helper Code

```
interface Robot {

    boolean move(Position current, Direction direction, int[][] grid);

    Direction turnLeft(Direction currentDirection);
    Direction turnRight(Direction currentDirection);
    boolean clean();
}

class RobotImpl implements Robot {

    Position currentPosition;
    Direction currentDirection;
    int moveCount = 0;
    int rotationCount = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean move(Position current, Direction direction, int[][] grid) {
        if(current.x == grid.length || current.x < 0 || current.y == grid[0].length || current.y < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        Position newPosition = getNewPosition(current, direction);
        if(grid[newPosition.x][newPosition.y] == 1) {
            return false;
        }
        this.currentPosition = newPosition;
        moveCount++;
        return true;
    }

    private Position getNewPosition(Position current, Direction direction) {
        switch(direction) {
            case UP:
                current.y--;
                break;
            case DOWN:
                current.y++;
                break;
            case LEFT:
                current.x--;
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                current.x++;
                break;
        }
        return current;
    }

    @Override
    public Direction turnLeft(Direction currentDirection) {
        switch(currentDirection) {
            case UP:
                currentDirection = Direction.LEFT;
                break;
            case LEFT:
                currentDirection = Direction.DOWN;
                break;
            case DOWN:
                currentDirection = Direction.RIGHT;
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                currentDirection = Direction.UP;
                break;
        }
        rotationCount++;
        return currentDirection;
    }

    @Override
    public Direction turnRight(Direction currentDirection) {
        switch(currentDirection) {
            case UP:
                currentDirection = Direction.RIGHT;
                break;
            case LEFT:
                currentDirection = Direction.UP;
                break;
            case DOWN:
                currentDirection = Direction.LEFT;
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                currentDirection = Direction.DOWN;
                break;
        }
        rotationCount++;
        return currentDirection;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean clean() {
        return true;
    }
}

class Pair {
    int moves;
    int rotations;

    Pair(int moves, int rotations) {
        this.moves = moves;
        this.rotations = rotations;
    }
}

enum Direction {
    LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN
}

class Position {
    int x, y;

    Position(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Return the minimum steps required by robot to clean every land cell (if robot visits a cell, it is cleaned) along with minimum number of rotations required.
Constraint: Need to use BFS to visit cells instead of DFS.

Need to fill the function:
`public Pair bfs(int[][] grid, Position currentPosition, Robot robot, Direction currentDirection)`

Tried couple of implementation of Breadth First Search but was unable to complete.
Can someone help in completing the function to return minimum number of moves along with minimum number of rotations required. It was mentioned that you can't use Depth First Search, you need to use Breadth First Search only.

Comment: You should tag your question with the coding language.

Comment: @Mayank, what are the constraints of this problem. Any maximum size for the grid, maximum number of land cells?

Comment: *"minimum steps required... minimum number of rotations"*:  What if there is a solution with 200 steps and 12 rotations, while another solution has 210 steps and 8 rotations? Which one is "best"?

Comment: @trincot, there's no constraint given on size of grid or max number of land calls. It is just mentioned that all the land cells are reachable although. But grid is of finite size, not infinite.

Comment: @trincot, out of steps and rotations, first constraint is to minimise steps. If steps are equal then minimize rotations.

Answer (score 0):

This is the travelling salesman problem, which is notoriously hard.  You likely want some approximation that will give a good result in your particular case, e.g. allow some vertices to be revisited.  A good start would be to google 'Metric Travelling Salesman approximation' Shortcut: look at [http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~cowen/advanced/2002/adv-lect3.pdf](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/%7Ecowen/advanced/2002/adv-lect3.pdf)

Basic algorithm

1. convert the grid to a graph with vertices and edges.  Adjacent cells are linked if neither is an obstacle.
2. Find the minimum spanning tree of the graph (  Kruskal’s or Prim’s algorithm )
3. Search through the tree to find the path, backtracking when you reach a leaf.

Note that step 3 uses a depth first search.  I cannot imagine how breadth first search could produce a good solution - every step would then be followed by a backtrack to search the other adjacencies.

There are a great many detailed variations on how to implement the details of this - it is a huge topic.  To see some of the possibilities take a look at https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder, in particular the obstacles application https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinderFeb2023/wiki/Obstacles

Comment: But in traveling salesman problem, you can't go to a visited node again, but in this case you can visit node again as well

Comment: That is what I mean by an approximation.  You want to minimize the number of revisits but allow enough to make the solution feasible and quickly found.